# What are the $p$-adic representations of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ ?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

A continuous representation $\hat{\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is determined by the image of $1$. But the image of $1$ does not always defines such a representation (consider for example the representation which sends $1$ on $p$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $GL_1(\mathbb{Q}_p)$). So my question is : what are the conditions on the image of $1$ ?

For example if $n=1$, then I know that $1$ must be sent on an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, but I don't know if the converse is true.

EDIT: Correction about the example.

Comment: I think the answer is going to be that a matrix can be the image of 1 iff it's conjugate to an element of $GL(n,\mathbf{Z}_p)$, i.e. iff it stabilises a lattice. If $n=1$ then this reduces to what you suggest, and it is iff in this case because valuation is a continuous map and there are no continuous maps from $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$ with its profinite topology to $\mathbf{Z}$ with its discrete topology other than the trivial one sending everything to 0 (as the continuous image of compact is compact, but the only compact subgroup of the integers is trivial).

Comment: The necessart and sufficient condition is that the characteristic of the candidate image of $1$ has characteristic polynomial with $\mathbb Z_p$-coefficients.

Comment: @Torsten: that's not right. The 1x1 matrix (p) has char poly in Z_p.

Comment: I'm not entirely right either: instead of "stabilises a lattice" I should say it induces an _isomorphism_ from a lattice to itself.

Comment: If the image of 1 lands in some conjugate of GL(n,Z_p) then some finite power will land in the kernel of the map from this group to GL(n,Z/pZ) and then you're fine because this is pro-p and so there's a map from Z_p in. So the condition I suggest is sufficient.

Comment: The condition I suggest is also necessary. Choose a random lattice in Q_p^n. Choose a continuous representation of Z-hat. Continuous image of compact is compact so the subgroup generated by the images of this lattice is a lattice and that's the one which is preserved by 1 and -1. Ok so I think we're done.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the condition that the constant term must be invertible.

Comment: Ok so I think everything is now consistent :-)

Comment: @Kevin: yes I think so! Just to recap: the continuous image of a compact set is compact so the image has to land in a compact subgroup of $GL_n(Q_p)$ which we know is conjugate to a subgroup of $GL_n(Z_p)$. Conversely if $M = card(GL_n(F_p))$ and $f(1)$ is (say) in $GL_n(Z_p)$ then for every $k$, the image of $p^{k-1}M Z$ is in $1+p^k M_n(Z_p)$ so the map from $Z$ extends by uniform continuity.

To relate this to Torsten's answer, it remains to check that a matrix is conjugate to an element of $GL_n(Z_p)$ iff its char poly has integral coeffts.

Comment: @Laurent: One direction is clear, for the other if $T=f(1)$ as $T$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, the $\mathbb Z_p$-module spanned by $T^{i-1}e_j$, $i,j=1,...,n$ is a $T$-stable $\mathbb Z_p$-lattice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am going to write a community wiki answer here which people can vote up.
(See [this meta thread](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/780) concerning the Mathoverflow user,
which bumps questions with no voted-up answer.)

Main result: A homomorphism $f: \mathbb Z \to GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ extends continuously to
$\hat{\mathbb Z}$ if and only if the image of $f$ can be conjugated into $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Proof:
If $f:\hat{\mathbb Z} \to GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is continuous, the image is compact, hence contained 
in a maximal compact subgroup, which can be conjugated into $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Conversely, if $f:\mathbb Z \to GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ lands in a compact subgroup,
then the closure of the image is compact, hence profinite (any compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is profinite), and hence $f$ extends to $\hat{\mathbb Z}$
(since $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ is precisely the profinite completion of $\mathbb Z$).
QED

As noted in the comments, to tell if a matrix (e.g. $f(1)$) can be conjugated into
$GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$, one simply has to look at the characteristic polynomial,
and ask that all the coefficients lie in $\mathbb Z_p$, with the constant term being
a unit.  Thus to apply the theorem in practice, one simply computes the characteristic polynomial of $f(1)$ and see if its satisfies these conditions.

EDIT: Now actually made community wiki; sorry about that --- I thought I had already clicked the CW box,
but obviously not.  (The point is that the above argument is just a rephrasing of what is in the comments.)